What does this $PATH output mean?
I ran in terminal:
echo $PATH

the output is this:
/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

Is anyone familiar with those directories? I am worried it is malware. Any info is appreciated!

What directories? Without knowing anything about the system, it can't be determined why directories are in the $PATH for that user or what put them there.

Related - What is the right format of PATH variable

Related - When does the shell search PATH?

Related - What exactly is the PATH variable for...

Related - How does lookup in $PATH work under the hood?

I assume the issue is the entries containing com.apple.security.cryptexd. A brief Google gives "Those cryptexd paths seem to be part of Apple's new Rapid Security Response mechanism.". Your trail starts there.

It appears you are using iOS.  Cryptex is a native Apple component to ship cryptographically signed software updates:

The cryptex subsystem allows a researcher to load a personalized trust cache and a disk image containing corresponding content.

So there's nothing to worry about.

Cryptexes are used for managing system components and updates securely without modifying the core System volume directly. They are used for more flexible and secure updates. More info here and here.
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

(found in /private/etc/paths.d/10-cryptex) and /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin paths are references to the Cryptex System on macOS.
These $PATH variables were most likely setup when you selected to "Install Security Responses and system files" in System Settings > General > Software Update.
During the update process, the system might use temporary directories to manage or prepare these updates before they are fully integrated into the system.
The /var/run directory is used for runtime data, which can include temporary or dynamically created paths. The directories under com.apple.security.cryptexd are most likely used for temporary Cryptex mounts or operations as:
ls /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/
comes up empty.

The PATH environment variable is an ordered, colon-separated, list of directories. These directories are searched for executables matching commands you type. Read man $SHELL to see exactly when the PATH search takes place.
When dealing with "colon-separated" lists (PATH is one example) I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935
The addpath function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. delpath -n deletes all non-existent directories from a path. listpath lists a path.
You can get the pathfunc.tgz file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

You describu the PATH variable, but I believe the user is more concerned with the contents of their PATH variable, specifically the entries that start with /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd ("Is anyone familiar with those directories?").

@Kusalananda There's also the /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin, but since the OP didn't specify exactly which directories are in question, we cannot be certain.
